# Vote statistics gone

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, profile-page, statistics

The votes by day and week statistics in the profile page reset on a new month and display the wrong value for the week.

[image: Vote statistics]

Comment: It's a new month. But not a new week. Mine shows 2 votes for the week. That's clearly wrong.

Comment: I just voted on Stackoverflow and no additional votes for day or month appeared after waiting a few minutes.

Comment: @juergend: The stats are cached, it takes a small amount of time for vote counts to update.

Comment: Now the vote is displayed in the statictics. But Mystical is right - one vote per week can't be right.

Comment: Looks like that week is not the week we think it is. Or more likely, new month "reset" the weekly vote count which is a bug indeed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query was incorrect here, not accounting for the fact a week can start before a month does in the overall set it was tallying (e.g. `WHERE v.CreationDate >= @thisMonth` rather than `@minOfMonthAndWeekStartDates` - we don't really name variables like that, calm down).

Obviously this isn't consistent with everywhere else and wasn't intended.  The bug will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: What's wrong with those variable names? :)